# Making my function that iterates through excel sheets more efficient

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance, for-loop

I have written the following function for a program that is supposed to search through an excel file and manipulate data frames, but the function is insanely slow and I am not sure how to make it more efficient. is there another way to iterate through excel sheets that works better than this?

```
def read_masterfile(masterfile_path):
sheets_dict = pd.ExcelFile(masterfile_path).sheet_names
for sheet in sheets_dict:
    df = pd.read_excel(masterfile_path, sheet_name = sheet)
    print(sheet)
    print(df.columns)

user_input= input() 
masterfile_dir = (r"C:\Users\path\Desktop\July15\masterfile.xlsx")
if user_input == 'y': 
   calculated = read_masterfile(masterfile_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing the following:

```
for sheet in sheets_dict:
    df = pd.read_excel(masterfile_path, sheet_name = sheet)
```

You are opening the excel file from zero multiple times. I would guess this is what's causing your code to be slow.

You can read all the sheets on one excel file using:

```
pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None)
```

This will return a dictionary where the keys are sheet names and the values are dataframes.